# I have 2 columns referenced from another table A, and I want to display usernames as they are saved in in table B

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I know how to display name instead of id in Yii framework in gridview and detail view.

Here is part of codes in view.php

```
 <?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'condensed' => false,
    'hover' => true,

    'attributes' => [
        'user_branch_id',
        //'user_id',
        [
            'attribute'=>'user_id',
           'value' =>$model->user->username,
        ],

        //'branch_id',
        [
            'attribute'=>'branch_id',
           'value' =>$model->branch->branch_name,
        ],
        'status',
       /* [
            'attribute' => 'created_at',
            'format' => [
                'datetime', (isset(Yii::$app->modules['datecontrol']['displaySettings']['datetime']))
                    ? Yii::$app->modules['datecontrol']['displaySettings']['datetime']
                    : 'd-m-Y H:i:s A'
            ],
            'type' => DetailView::INPUT_WIDGET,
            'widgetOptions' => [
                'class' => DateControl::classname(),
                'type' => DateControl::FORMAT_DATETIME
            ]
        ],
        */
       **// 'created_by',
        [
            'attribute'=>'created_by',
           'value' =>$model->user->username,
        ],**
        [
            'attribute' => 'last_update',
            'format' => [
                'datetime', (isset(Yii::$app->modules['datecontrol']['displaySettings']['datetime']))
                    ? Yii::$app->modules['datecontrol']['displaySettings']['datetime']
                    : 'd-m-Y H:i:s A'
            ],
            'type' => DetailView::INPUT_WIDGET,
            'widgetOptions' => [
                'class' => DateControl::classname(),
                'type' => DateControl::FORMAT_DATETIME
            ]
        ],

    ],
    'deleteOptions' => [
        'url' => ['delete', 'id' => $model->user_id],
    ],
    'enableEditMode' => true,
]) ?>
```

I have these attributes:

```
1. [
                'attribute'=>'user_id',
               'value' =>$model->user->username,
            ],
 2. [
                'attribute'=>'created_by',
               'value' =>$model->user->username,
            ],
```

when I retrieve as shown on a screenshot below, it show same username, while id are different i.e.

column created_by: 1
column user_id: 3

[image: 1]

Comment: You're using the same variable (`$model->user->username`) in both cases, why did you expecting to get different values from the same variable?

Comment: You will have the same username because you wrote `'value' =>$model->user->username,` in two different attributes.

Comment: Yes I use same ' 'value'=>$model->user->username' because I wanted to display username instead of id (FK) on this view.

Here is a table structure
'
...............
`user_branch_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
 `branch_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
 `status` ENUM('ACTIVE','INACTIVE') NOT NULL,
 `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `last_update` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `created_by` INT(11) NOT NULL,
........'

Comment: ** user_id & created_by** are fk referencing same table but 'user_id'
can hold various values with 'created_by' same value

Comment: here is a data sample rows.

row 1. 'user_id:1' and  'created_by:1'
row 2. 'user_id:2' and  'created_by:1'
row 3. 'user_id:3' and  'created_by:1'

In a 'user table', here' id:1=> username:chirie' and 'id:2=>username:kiprokorir', so how can this scenario of **row 2.** 'user_id:2' and  'created_by:1' be achieved??

Answer (score 0):

**Finally I solve my problem,** at the model, because two columns are foreign keys from same table **user**, the model generate two get functions

1. **getUser()**
2. **getCreatedBy**

Then my code solutions are 
            `[
               'attribute'=>'user_id',
               'value' =>$model->user->username,
            ],
             'attribute'=>'created_by',
               'value' =>$model->createdBy->username,
            ],`